# Kafka Connect, JDBC connector password in clear text. How to avoid?

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a jdbc source connector that I'm using, and I've been using Postman to test and set this. The password for the db connection is in clear text, which is fine as long as I'm the only one seeing it.

```
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:db2://db2server.mycompany.com:4461/myDB",
        "connection.user: "dbUser",
        "connection.password": "DBPASSinClearText!",
        "dialect.name": "Db2DatabaseDialect",
        "mode": "timestamp",
        "query": "select fname, lname, custId, custRegion, lastUpdate from CustomerMaster",
        "timestamp.column.name": "lastUpdate",
        "table.types": "TABLE",
        "topic.prefix": "master.customer"
    }
}
```

In production, the deployment team are the ones who set the config. Is there a way to encrypt this, so I don't have to share the clear text password with that team?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can use externalise the credentials. This was added in Apache Kafka 2.0 through [KIP-297](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-297%3A+Externalizing+Secrets+for+Connect+Configurations).

You can use external credential providers (a basic example would be a flat file), and then instead of this:

```js
"connection.password": "DBPASSinClearText!",
```

you'd have something like:

```js
"connection.password": "${file:/data/foo_credentials.properties:FOO_PASSWORD}",
```

[Here's an example](https://rmoff.net/2019/05/24/putting-kafka-connect-passwords-in-a-separate-file-/-externalising-secrets/) of doing it with just a flat file, and read more about the functionality in full in [the docs here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/security.html#externalizing-secrets)

Comment: @Lee O. typed faster than I did :)

Comment: Thanks, I got it working. It would be really nice if there were support for something like this: 

"connection.password":"${file:myhost.com/data/foo_credentials.properties:PASSWORD}",

If Kafka is running on kafkahost.com, and i don't want to share credentials with that Ops team, I can put the credentials file on myhost.com and give read access to whatever ID is running Kafka on kafkahost.com.

Comment: @M.Ferris `ConfigProvider` is an open interface. Feel free to implement that yourself. Or use Hashicorp Vault, like the other answer shows

Answer (score 2):

At my company we created an API over the top of kafka connect where we use variables in the config and Hashicorp Vault for the values.

But you can use a ConfigProvider as outlined in the docs at https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/security.html#externalizing-secrets. If storing the secrets in plain text config files in kafka doesn't work for you, it's possible to create your own implementation of the ConfigProvider.

Comment: @cricket_007 Nice! We'll have to look into using that.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up starting the kafka connect docker container and piping through `sed`.

From our kubes terraform definition.

```
command = ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/etc/confluent/docker/run | sed -e 's/password=[^$]*/password=****/g' "]
```

Feels like a hack, but its Friday afternoon and time for a beer.